# Saving output of :map in vim

Tags: vim

Q1: Is there a way of saving the output of the command

```
:map
```

to a file?

Q2: In a related question, I have the following map in my vimrc file:

```
map <f1> :wa<cr>
```

When I load a latex file (I have the vim-latex plugin installed), the
F1 key now invokes help.
Is there a way of changing this without manually having to type the map again?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A1: To redirect/save the output of `:map`:

```
:redir >> ~/mymaps.txt
:map
:redir END
```

A2:

As kemp says, you can find it using `verbose` and modify the plugin file.

Or you can create a vim file in your plugins directory that runs last, e.g., `~/.vim/plugin/zzzmyremaps.vim` (check by running scriptnames)

*Edit:* rampion is correct in the comments. Because this is a filetype issue, this should be handled in the after directory `~/.vim/after/plugin/latex.vim` as the offending latex.vim file is not being loaded on startup but on a buffer enter.

Note `.vimrc` gets sourced first so plugins have a habit of overwriting them. `:scriptnames` will show the order.

Comment: The standard way of ensuring that your that your settings are read last is to use your `after` directory: `~/.vim/after/plugin/latex.vim` ~ that will be read after the standard vim-latex plugin, and you can fix anything that they do that you don't like.

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is that `<F1>` gets remapped, you can use `:verbose map <F1>` to see where it is defined, and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can resource the .vimrc file again.  Something like:

```
map <f2> :source /path/to/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to save the individual `:map`, but `:mksession filename` will save a file with the current state of the editor in it, which will include all the `map` definitions.