# Mapping already in use: "<LocalLeader>sb", mode "n"

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I recently installed some plugins so I can use Vim as my development IDE. It appears some of the plugins are not playing nicely with each other.

Currently, I have the following vim plugins in my plugin directory:

- code_complete.vim
- cscope_maps.vim
- doxygen-support.vim
- sourcebeautify
- taglist.vim
- vcscommand.vim
- vcsgit.vim
- vcssvk.vim
- crefvim.vim
- c.vim
- minibufexpl.vim
- symfony.vim
- vcsbzr.vim
- vcscvs.vim
- vcshg.vim
- vcssvn.vim

My ~/.vimrc file has the following contents:

```
autocmd BufRead *.vala,*.vapi set efm=%f:%l.%c-%[%^:]%#:\ %t%[%^:]%#:\ %m
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.vala,*.vapi setfiletype vala

set nocp ts=4 sw=4 noet ai cin bs=2 cb=unnamed
set number ruler wrap autoread showcmd showmode fdm=marker nobackup
syntax on
filetype plugin on

set incsearch
set tags=./tags;/
map <C-\> :tab split<CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
map <A-]> :vsp <CR>:exec("tag ".expand("<cword>"))<CR>
```

When I attempt to open a C or C++ file, I get the following warning message:

```
Mapping already in use: "<LocalLeader>sb", mode "n"
Press Enter to Continue
```

Does anyone know which of the plugins is causing this, and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Use `:verbose map` to see a list of all the mappings and what file defines them. That will narrow it down.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: verbose map produces several screenfulls of text. I used the answer to  this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239226/saving-output-of-map-in-vim to dump the data to a 9.3K file. Now I just need somewhere to upload that file to. Alternatively, maybe you/someone can tell me how to use the dumped data to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

`:verbose map <LocalLeader>sb`

this will show you which plugin(s) set that mapping