# How to search through vim keymaps?

Tags: vim, key-bindings, keymapping

I often forget infrequently used keymappings, but i roughly remember the command name like `make` or `PlugInstall`.
When i open `:nmap` i have to scroll through a long list of mappings to find the one i look for.

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2240892/4936725 i currently export the keybindings into a file and grep through that.

```
:redir >> ~/mymaps.txt
:map
:redir END
```

Is there a more convenient way to search or grep through the keymaps list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim 8 has introduced the [`:help :filter`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Afilter) command that allows you to directly grep the output of a `:map` command:

```
:filter /make/ nmap
```

This is good for a quick-and-dirty lookup. You still get annoying false positives like `<Plug>` mappings, though. For a robust solution, you'd probably still capture the output with `:redir`, then `split()` it into lines and `filter()` (via multiple passes) for matching output.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Just out of curiosity: Is there something similar with fuzzy search?

Comment: Vim doesn't have any fuzzy matching built in, but it would be possible to implement following what I outlined. Actually, I use something like that for myself, feeding available mappings to a fork of the fuf.vim plugin.